# How do I write this PL/SQL anonymous block so that the output is in reverse order?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
ENAME     VARCHAR2(10);
SAL       NUMBER(7,2);
CURSOR    C1 IS SELECT ENAME, SAL
          FROM EMP
          WHERE ROWNUM < 11;
BEGIN
     OPEN C1;
     LOOP
          FETCH C1 INTO ENAME, SAL;
          EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ENAME ||' '|| SAL);
     END LOOP;
END;
/
```

This is the output

```
KING 5000
BLAKE 2850
CLARK 2450
JONES 2975
MARTIN 1250
ALLEN 1600
TURNER 1500
JAMES 950
WARD 1250
FORD 3000
```

I am having trouble with displaying the output in reverse order.

For reference this is the question proposed to me:

Write a PL/SQL anonymous block that will process records stored in the "emp" table. The program must perform the following tasks.

1. Declare the required types and variables to store both the employee name and salary information.
2. Use a loop to retrieve the first 10 "ename" and "sal" values for records in the "emp" table, store in two variable array of 10 elements.
3. Use another loop to display the "ename" and "sal" values in the reverse order.

As stated before I am having issue with the third task.

Thanks for your help ahead of time.

Comment: You need an array and append elements to it, then iterate from highest index to lowest.

Comment: What does your teacher (or your textbook) mean by "the first 10" values? Rows in a table are like balls in a basket: they are not ordered. Without a marker of some sort (such as "first 10 IN ORDER OF HIRE_DATE") the requirement is meaningless. Your teacher (or your textbook) would not pass my introductory SQL class, if I ever taught one.

Comment: @mathguy This is from my teacher. He added to use pseudocolumn "ROWNUM"  to limit the number of salaries to select 10 in no particular order. There are 14 records in the table, I am assuming he only wants the first 10.

Comment: OK, got it - the additional directive was missing, and too often we see requirement where that clarification actually does not exist. The teacher asked you to create the "required types and variables"; he or she probably wanted you to create a record type to hold a name and an employee number (together in a single record), and declare an array of such records, as Kamil G suggested, and then in a loop to print the elements of the array, running the index from 10 to 1.

Comment: @mathguy OK, that makes sense - I want to make sure I get the syntax correct as I am pretty new to PL/SQL. For VARRAY would it be                        TYPE ename IS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2(10);

Answer (score 0):

**Use an implicit cursor and assign records to an associative array**

Declare an associative array (aka index by table) and assign emp records
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS99969

When I hit ten records, I have an if then statement which prints the 10 records of this associative array in reverse order.

I include nominal error handling.

```
   SCOTT@dev>DECLARE
  2      TYPE emp_rec_typ IS RECORD (
  3          ename     emp.ename%TYPE,
  4          sal       emp.sal%TYPE
  5      );
  6      TYPE emp_tab_typ IS
  7          TABLE OF emp_rec_typ INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  8      n         BINARY_INTEGER;
  9      emp_tab   emp_tab_typ;
 10  BEGIN
 11      n := 0;
 12      FOR emp_rec IN (
 13          SELECT
 14              ename,
 15              sal
 16          FROM
 17              emp
 18          FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
 19      ) LOOP
 20          BEGIN
 21              n := n + 1;
 22              emp_tab(n) := emp_rec;
 23              dbms_output.put_line(emp_rec.ename
 24               || ' '
 25               || TO_CHAR(emp_rec.sal) );
 26  
 27              IF
 28                  n = 10
 29              THEN
 30                  dbms_output.put_line('-------------');
 31                  dbms_output.put_line('reverse order');
 32                  dbms_output.put_line('-------------');
 33                  FOR n IN REVERSE 1..10 LOOP
 34                      dbms_output.put_line(emp_tab(n).ename
 35                       || ' '
 36                       || TO_CHAR(emp_tab(n).sal) );
 37                  END LOOP;
 38  
 39              END IF;
 40  
 41          EXCEPTION
 42              WHEN OTHERS THEN
 43                  dbms_output.put(sqlcode || ' ' || sqlerrm);
 44          END;
 45      END LOOP;
 46  
 47  END;
 48  /
SMITH 800
ALLEN 1600
WARD 1250
JONES 2975
MARTIN 1250
BLAKE 2850
CLARK 2450
SCOTT 3000
KING 5000
TURNER 1500
-------------
reverse order
-------------
TURNER 1500
KING 5000
SCOTT 3000
CLARK 2450
BLAKE 2850
MARTIN 1250
JONES 2975
WARD 1250
ALLEN 1600
SMITH 800


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

---

*addendum*

-I suppose I should have used two varrays instead of the associative array (requirement #2).  That would have been simpler in terms of writing.

-Per the comments, I suppose I could have used ROWNUM but I prefer the row limiting clause instead.